# Mockito argument matchers InvalidUseOfMatchersException for Scala Project

Tags: scala, mockito

I have this Scala project that I am using mockito (mockito-core 3.0) to test

Here's the function signature of the function I am trying to mock

```
def hset[V: ByteStringSerializer](key: String, field: String, value: V): Future[Boolean] = ...
```

This doesnt work

```
verify(mockObj, never()).hset(anyString(), anyString(), anyLong())
```

Error outs with this

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

Not sure why its expecting 4 matchers when the function has 3 argument with a generics type

This works

```
verify(mockObj, never()).hset("a", "b", 3.0)
```

is this because I am using scala code which doesnt operate correctly with the mockito core ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem is [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html)

```
def hset[V: ByteStringSerializer](key: String, field: String, value: V): Future[Boolean]
```

is actually

```
def hset[V](key: String, field: String, value: V)(implicit ev: ByteStringSerializer[V]): Future[Boolean]
```

Now you can see why there are 4 arguments, try

```
verify(mockObj, never()).hset(anyString(), anyString(), anyLong())(any(classOf[ByteStringSerializer[Long]]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I just thought it was regular generics.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan pointed out, you're missing the matcher for the implicit.
I'd suggest you to migrate to mockito-scala as this kind of scenarios will work out-of-the-box when the implicit is in scope